# How do I begin to explain that my orcs may survive by eating soil?

Tags: xenobiology, food, fantasy-races

In my RPG campaign setting the orcs are tougher than most other races.  In hard
times they can eat wood (small bushes and fresh pieces of trees).  In
really hard times they can eat healthy soil and survive enough to continue
their march/siege, but they don't like it.

How do I begin to explain this process?

While I could hand-wave it away with the word "magic," I'd like to have at
least a believable starting point

Comment: Directly processing the trace elements -- or eating micro-flora/fauna that do the same.

Comment: Have you read about Orks? Seriously have a look at the Warhammer 40,000 [Orks](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Orks) they're half fungus and have some of the characteristics you seem to be after.

Comment: Earthworms eat soil ([sort of](https://www.reference.com/pets-animals/earthworms-eat-soil-3b3d2a75eafb56e8)). Are your orcs biologically related to earthowrms perhaps?

Comment: Why not just have it be [the same way that humans do?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geophagia#Contemporary_practices) (Oh, just realized there's an answer already touching on this. I'll leave the link in case it's useful.)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Starting from the ground up: how much caloric energy even exists in the things orcs eat?  Energy metabolism for aerobes involves combining oxidizable with oxygen - in essence burning them.  One can burn things in a bomb calorimeter to see what the caloric value is.  I looked up caloric values for fats, ethanol, protein and conventional carbohydrates (e.g. wheat flour); then wood and leaves, then various soils.

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Food_energy

> Fats and ethanol have the greatest amount of food energy per gram, 37
>   and 29 kJ/g **(8.8 and 6.9 kcal/g)**, respectively. Proteins and most
>   carbohydrates have about 17 kJ/g (4 kcal/g).

from [source](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.2307/1936045/asset/ecy1971525923.pdf;jsessionid=02541A2796915DCB72C43370AD40463A.f01t04?v=1&t=j63170ts&s=b22ce8be822742a3691c3c871563ea673a269be3)
[image]

from [Caloric values of organic matter in woodland, swamp, and lake soils](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1932684?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

> Caloric values of organic matter in woodland, swamp, and aquatic soils (± standard deviation of the mean)
>   $$
> \begin{array}{c|cc} \text{Soil Type} & \text{Kcal/g
> ash-free
> dry wt} & \text{Ignition
> loss%
> dry wt} \\
> \hline
> \text{11 woodland humus layers} & 5.04±0.04 & 57 .5±5.7\\
> \text{20 swamp soils} & 4.87±0.04 & 77 .3±1.5\\
> \text{9 lake and pond muds} & 5.24±0.05 & 59.3 ±3.6 \\
> \end{array}
> $$

So: for a fire, carbs, proteins, wood, leaves and soils all have comparable energy value - 4 to 5 kcal/g.  I was surprised to read it for soil.  Why can't you make a fire from dirt, then?  Maybe my efforts have used dirt with too much sand or clay; the authors of the soil article specify that this is topsoil rich in organic matter, not deeper mineral soils.

Then why can humans eat corn but not wood?  The calories in wood, tree leaves and soil are mostly as cellulose: the evolutionary masterwork of the plants.  It is made of sugar and very much a carbohydrate, as energy dense as starch, but very difficult to digest.

To digest it one must have commensal bacterial to do the job.  These live in the specialized gut organ called the rumen in ruminants (like cows), also in the less specialized digestive tracts of pandas, and in the cecum (part of the colon) of rabbits.

The problem rabbits have is that the cecum comes after the small intestine, and the small intestine is where nutrients are absorbed from broken down food.  What good is it for your bacteria to break down cellulose into sugar if you can't soak up some of the sugar because you are about to poop it out?

The rabbit solution: refection.  Eat the poop.  That poop is full of microbes breaking down the cellulose.  Give them a while and that poop is full of nutritious sugars.  Back in it goes to absorbed the second time around.

from http://www.columbia.edu/itc/cerc/danoff-burg/invasion_bio/inv_spp_summ/Oryctolagus_cuniculus.htm

> European rabbits are ravenous eaters and indulge in a diverse diet of
>   grasses, roots, tree bark, leaves, grains, fruit, seeds, and buds.
>   Since this diet is low in nutritional value and high in
>   difficult-to-digest materials, they are known to reingest their feces
>   to obtain extra nutritional value from the food the second time
>   around.

Your orcs are set up the same way.  They can extract energy value from twigs, leaves and soils by letting their colonic commensal bacteria break it down, then re-eating the product.

This also explains why they don't like it.

Comment: +1 for the good answer. But even if I didn't like the answer: +1 for 'This also explains why they don't like it'

Comment: "Why can't you make a fire from dirt, then?" I would imagine Thermodynamics is not in your favor. This is also something that must be taken into account. A system that wants to process dirt to make energy, but have a proper chemical/biological pathway to do so.

Comment: Still having a hard time reconciling "rabbits/bunnies" and "orcs" in a single chain of thought that does not include violence or one eating the other.

Comment: @LiveMynd : "Look - that rabbit's got a vicious streak a mile wide!  It's a killer!"

Comment: Wait, can rabbits tell the difference between poop that they've digested once and poop that they've digested twice?

Comment: @Will: Of course someone had to reference Monty Python. :P Incidentally, John Cleese wrote in his autobiography that he was bitten by a rabbit when he was a kid -- explains where that idea came from.

Comment: @aidan.plenert.macdonald The quoted source shows that thermodynamics *is* in your favour - *provided the soil is dry*.  However, a) soil is quite dense, so it will often stop air getting to the fire - and put it out (apparently parafin/kerosene [has been used](https://books.google.ch/books?id=R98DAAAAMBAJ&lpg=PA434&ots=vwcmCrS7Oa&pg=PA434) to put out cotton bales that are on fire - it soaks in better than water). b) The soil is probably damp, and boiling out the water is also quite likely to remove enough heat to put out the fire.

Comment: @Erty Seidohl  yes, the 2 substances are different enough to have different names.  IT's called cecotropes and is coated by a special mucus

Comment: @ErtySeidohl: not just them — *you* can easily tell the difference, if you go walking by a rabbit warren.  The once-digested pellets are dense, with a sticky shiny mucus on the outside.  The twice-digested ones are more fibrous, and dry out more quickly.

Comment: I hope there is a scene where the orcs are arguing among themselves about which type a given piece represents.  "Naw, it's good.  Lookit the mucus on that one!"

Answer (score 23):

It is possible, because it is real.

See documentary video "Haitians eat dirt cookies to survive" 
https://youtu.be/s3337cj4sJQ

Also, in Vietnam (use google translate to read):
http://news.zing.vn/nuong-dat-de-an-o-vinh-phuc-post396355.html

Comment: Real world examples.  Cool!

Comment: Not only Haititians. Peasants in my own country did this during famine (1907). You can imagine uprisings followed shortly after.

Comment: @Magicsowon what is your country ?

Comment: @HahaTTpro looks like it might be china - wikipedia lists a famine with 25 million (holy carp!) dead there in 1907, and some more googling tells me that there were uprisings after that (understandably)

Comment: I was about to answer along these lines. Although I don't have any reliable reference, I've heard, as a kid, that some indigenous peoples here in Brazil have (or had, in the past) a sort of dish made of "cooked earth" as **part** of their diet.

Answer (score 4):

Loam (consists of sand clay, silt and any organic and water mixed in) contains vegetation that is breaking down.  Often forest floors have layers of leaves lost each year.  The carbohydrates that make a leave structure will give on energy when oxidized.  Same as other food. They can also eat live roots, shoots, grubs, worms, bacteria, slugs.  Fungi are usually present as single cells even if they do not show a cap above ground.

It is likely that sand and clay cause constipation.

Compost piles can have many of the possible nutrients that are in loam.  Smashing everything and manufacturing a large pile of rot seams appropriate  behavior for orcs.

You could have a preferred fungus that the orc bands carry with them.  The fungus will have the enzymes that convert chewed beta cellulose (wood) into simple sugars.

Comment: Compost piles - painful condition caused by eating too much dirt.

Comment: About sand and clay causing constipation, I believe it is more up to mechanical properties of the digestive tract. Hens ingest small stones all the time, and these actually play an important part in their digestion. Also, I've seen dogs eating large amounts of sand and having no apparent trouble in getting rid of it later.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a slightly different approach, if your Orcs are green you could make the argument that they are able to perform limited photosynthesis in their skin, eating the dirt gives them the nutrients they need to perform photosynthesis which they don't usually get from their usual diet of meat and more meat.

Comment: photosynthesis on the skin gives orders of magnitudes less energy than what's necessary to move a humanoid body. That's why plants can't make significant movements for a prolonged time (except for building up tension for a long while and releasing it at once to disperse seeds, etc.)